# How to set timeout for terraform apply?

Tags: terraform

Many a times I get '[TRACE] dag/walk: vertex ' when I apply terraform apply on certain tf. I would like to set timeout instead of going on forever.

Thanks

Several examples - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16458
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2068

But all of them focus on specific solution. I dont want inifinite loops whatsoever reason I just want a flag for apply that would stop trying after certain time. Iam thinking of an external command to kill it but I want to see if there is actual terraform solution before I implement it.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and possibly the output? There's no universal way to timeout things or the whole action but some resources have configurable timeouts set on create/update/destroy. Is there a specific thing you would want to happen when hitting this timeout?

Answer (score 22):

Today Terraform SDK have special fields for resources timeouts. Official documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/syntax#operation-timeouts).

For example, you can add timeouts for some operations in resource description:

```
resource "<resource_name>" "<resource_name>" {
  ...
  timeouts {
    create = "1h30m"
    update = "2h"
    delete = "20m"
  }
}
```

Edit: Fixing terraform syntax

Comment: The documentation says, it is available just for some resources: "Some resource types provide a special timeouts"

Comment: not supported for data arguments it seems

Comment: What's up with the syntax here? Why colon instead of =? Documentation I see at the link below still uses equals and the documentation this answer links to also uses equals: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/retries-and-customizable-timeouts

Comment: This can not be an answer as it depends on the resource type. Most resource don't allow this and should have local timeout policies. Anyway, using the latest provider capabilities should help and mitigate the risks of timeout.